# Azure Function Failure : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named _cffi_backend

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

All,
My Azure Function is Failing with error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend

Here is my requirement.txt file

```
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
azure-identity
azure-storage-blob
requests
python-dateutil
cffi
```

My requirement file has cffi package and using devops pipeline these package get installed at runtime, generate .zip for azure functions. But its still failing.

I have tried by providing version number as well(PFB) still no luck.

```
azure-core==1.19.0
azure-storage-blob==12.9.0
azure-storage-file-datalake==12.4.0
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
charset-normalizer==2.0.6
cryptography==35.0.0
idna==3.2
isodate==0.6.0
msrest==0.6.21
oauthlib==3.1.1
pycparser==2.20
requests==2.26.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.7
msal
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend

After checking the error from my end,

**Need to check:**

1. The installed `cffi` version should be compatible with the `Python` version, as *`"cffi==1.14.6"`* was only officially supported up to Python 3.6.

Using python 3.8 and install the latest version of
cffi (2.21):

[image]

2.The pip version must also be updated to avoid errors like "ModuleNotFoundError:" type to occur as it contains all python packages&modules.

pip Upgrader:

```
    pip install pip-upgrader
```

> An interactive pip requirements upgrader. It also updates the version in your requirements.txt file.

After installed and checked the above reasons, I am able to execute the function successfully without any error.

***requirements.txt file:***

[image]

***init.py file:***

[image]

*If required, deploy to the Azure portal to verify it using the *"publish"* command.*

Comment: thank you for your response Jahnavi, I am using python 3.8 now and using cffi 2.21. Also I have added 'pip install pip-upgrader' in my DevOps pipeline , still no luck :( Here is my requirement.txt now (azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
azure-identity
azure-storage-blob
requests
python-dateutil
cffi)

Comment: also when I try run this function locally, I get error: ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch and cffi error when try to run using azure portal

Comment: *ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch* :  You need to set the required [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) in azure portal to run functions locally. Have you done that?

Comment: Alternative to check [module not found error](https://blog.finxter.com/fixed-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cffi/)

Comment: It seems issue is with my docker image. I was using ubuntu when I switch it to windows cffi error gone but now I am getting some other error. :(   ImportError: cannot import name 'ObjectIdentifier' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust'  How should we check what configuration my function would need when I have to run the same on Azure and not local system?

Comment: [Refer SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205819/cffi-fails-in-python-linux-virtual-environment-attempting-to-install-crypto) given by @murmur0m

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue. The rootcause was a discrepancy between the python version setup in the Azure Function and the python version used in the devops deployment pipeline. The Devops pipeline used python `3.9` and Azure function was using `3.10`.

I modified the python version in the Az function by going to `configurations` -> `general settings` -> `stack` and changed it to 3.9. This fixed my issue.